# Need help in Java recursion topic

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

This is my first time to ask a question here since I have searched so many times on Google and Youtube to learn how to use recursion in Java but I still can't understand what recursion is :( would you guys please help me?

I am working on a machine problem that will input the number of items greater than 10 in an array using a recursive function.

This is the code I have been working on and I'm receiving an error in line 24 saying:

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursion
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Greater g1 = new Greater();

        System.out.println("Enter number of items [1-10]: ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();

        g1.setNumber(number);

        for(int counter = 1; counter <= number; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number " + counter + ":" );
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int inputNumbers = sc2.nextInt();

            g1.setInputNumbers(inputNumbers);
        }

       System.out.println("The numbers greater than 10 are: " + g1.findGreater(inputNumbers));
}
```

}

This is the error:

"error: cannot find symbol

System.out.println("The numbers greater than 10 are: " +

g1.findGreater(inputNumbers));"

```
             ^
```

symbol: variable inputNumbers

location: class Recursion

Comment: "I still can't understand what recursion is" - maybe read on wikipedia? Bascially a recursion is that a method (sometimes) calls itself to do something. Or think about Russian dolls.

Comment: Thank you for the answers Koby and karim mohsen! But I have a question, how will I be able to input the numbers inside the for loop? I tried to remove the "int inputNumbers = sc2.nextInt();" and "g1.setInputNumbers(inputNumbers);" and placed them outside of the loop.

Comment: This is my recursive program:

  public int findGreater(int result)
  {
  if(inputNumbers < 10)
  {
   return result = 0;
  }
  else
  
  return result = findGreater(result + 1);
 }

can you guys atleast point to me what's wrong? :( because I'm completely new to recursion and it's really hard for me.

Comment: @JcOrdona There is no `inputNumbers`  in your function , your function only contains `result` variable where did you get `inputNumbers` ? . I think you should change your condition `if(inputNumbers < 10)` it has to do nothing with recursion

Comment: Thank you again for the reply karim mohsen! :) what I was trying to do in the function (which clearly fails :( ) is to check one by one the input numbers if they are greater than 10, then the result will be plus 1 for everytime there are numbers greater than 10. The (inputNumbers < 10) I think is the base case? :( I'm sorry I'm such a newbie Sir karim mohsen :( I really do appreciate your help for me!

Comment: This is the code of my other class:

public class Greater
{
 public int number;
 public int inputNumbers;
 public int result;
 
 public void setNumber(int n)
 {
  number = n;
 }
 
 public void setInputNumbers(int in)
 {
  inputNumbers = in;
 }
 
 public int getNumber()
 {
  return number;
 }
 
 public int getInputNumbers()
 {
  return inputNumbers;
 }

 public int findGreater(int result)
 {
  if(inputNumbers < 10)
  {
   return result = 0;
  }
  else
  
  return result = findGreater(result + 1);
 }
}

Comment: @JcOrdona i fixed your code here is the [link](http://jpst.it/BmVd)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help for me Sir karim mohsen! I will study the codes you have given to me. God bless Sir and keep on helping other people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variables created inside of a loop are **LOCAL TO THE LOOP**. This means that once you exit the loop, the variable can no longer be accessed! This includes any variables created in the loop signature.

Read more about [Scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)  in java

Answer (score 3):

See the error message. Your problem is you defined  inputNumbers variable inside the code block and it's not available outside in your system.out statement.

It's got nothing to do with recursion.